# Clarification on "intercept"?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, terminology, model, intercept

I'm currently reading "Competition-Based Dynamic Pricing in Online Retailing: A Methodology Validated" by Fisher, Gallino, and Li.  In the paper they mentioned that variables $\alpha_j$ and $\alpha_r$ are "intercepts."  Here's the relevant portion of the paper below:

[image: Description of variables]

By intercept, do they mean that the values of these variables are obtained from some graph somewhere?  Or do they just mean that they are intercepts of the above function $u_{ijr}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By intercepts they mean "biases", $\alpha_j$ for $j = 1,2,\dots,k$ are $k$ intercepts for each $j$-th level of the variable.

For example: you have country-level data and each country has its own intercept in the regression model. The intercept for $j$-th country is the "base rate" of the predicted variable for this country, corrected for other effects. In a simple intercepts-only model, the intercept would simply be the mean of the predicted variable for this country (assuming linear regression).

On implementation side, it's just a parameter multiplied by a dummy coded (or one-hot encoded) categorical variable.